# RegEx to find % symbols in a string that don't form the start of a legal two-digit escape sequence?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I would like a regular expression to find the `%`s in the source string that *don't* form the start of a valid two-hex-digit escaped character (defined as a `%` followed by exactly two hexadecimal digits, upper or lower case) that can be used to replace only these `%` symbols with `%25`.

(The motivation is to make the *best guess* attempt to create legally escaped strings from strings of various origins that may be legally percent escaped and may not, and may even be a mixture of the two, without damaging the data intent if the original string was already correctly encoded, e.g. by blanket re-encoding).

Here's an example input string.

> He%20has%20a%2050%%20chance%20of%20living%2C%20but%20there%27s%20only%20a%2025%%20chance%20of%20that.

This doesn't conform to any encoding standard because it is a mix of valid escaped characters eg. `%20` and two loose percentage symbols. I'd like to convert those `%`s to `%25`s.

My progress so far is to identify a regex `%[0-9a-z]{2}` that finds the % symbols that *are* legal but I can't work out how to modify it to find the ones that *aren't* legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})
```

Should do the trick. Use a look-ahead to find a `%` NOT followed by a valid two-digit hexadecimal value then replace the found `%` symbol with your `%25` replacement.

*(Hopefully this works with (presumably) NSRegularExpression, or whatever you're using)*

Comment: I'd go with a negative lookahead for simplicity, although this could be made to work.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: Touche, I was in reverse thinking pattern. I was looking for `%` WITH a valid hex digit following. Good catch, correcting it now.

Comment: It appears to work with `replaceOccurrencesOfString` `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive`. Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

`%(?![a-fA-F0-9]{2})`

That's a percent followed by a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for two hex digits.